# Flutter routing inside scaffold body

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to change scaffold body based upon url. How to routing inside scaffold body and keep appbar and bottombar common after user login . Is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this with [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) widget

```
class BaseLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(),
        ...
      ]),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIdx,
        children: [
          Page1(),
          Page2(),
          Page3(),
          //...and so on
      ....
```

Comment: Your example call various widgets. Not navigating new route. My question about call various routes